# Entry and Serialisation

Tags: serialization, hashmap

My project is in the form:

**Class Persistant :**

```
@Entity
public class Produit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3352484919001942398L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String module;
private String produit;

//getter&&setter
```

**Class Dao**

```
public  List<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> parProduit(String cat) {
.......
HashMap<Integer, List<Produit>> legaux = new HashMap<Integer, List<Produit>>();
........
List<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> entries = new    ArrayList<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>>(legaux.entrySet());

return entries;
}
```

when i execute this code i get this error :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.HashMap$Node
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.HashMap.EntrySet<K, V>
```

is not serializable.

```
legaux.entrySet()
```

probably returns set of type  java.util.HashMap.EntrySet, you may want to check that.

Comment: Even when i use : `Set<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> set = legaux.entrySet();
 List<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> list = new ArrayList<>(set);` I still get the same error